# Html and java script that moves object with arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, html, arrow-keys

Ok so I made a page that can move an image with the arrow keys but only the down and right functions work. I made the functions from a hide show script because i'm very new to javascript.

Here is the code.

left

```
function left(id) { 
    var y = '5';
    var z =document.getElementById(id).style.left;
    var x = parseInt(y)+parseInt(z);
    var state = document.getElementById(id).style.left;
        if (state == '1') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.left = x;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.left = x;
        }
    }
```

right

```
function right(id) { 
    var y = '5';
    var z =document.getElementById(id).style.right;
    var x = parseInt(y)+parseInt(z);
    var state = document.getElementById(id).style.right;
        if (state == '1') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.right = x;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.right = x;
        }
    }
```

up

```
function up(id) { 
    var y = '5';
    var z =document.getElementById(id).style.bottom;
    var x = parseInt(y)+parseInt(z);
    var state = document.getElementById(id).style.bottom;
        if (state == '1') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.bottom = x;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.bottom = x;
        }
    }
```

down

```
function down(id) { 
    var y = '5';
    var z =document.getElementById(id).style.top;
    var x = parseInt(y)+parseInt(z);
    var state = document.getElementById(id).style.top;
        if (state == '1') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.top = x;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.top = x;
        }
    }
```

then the arrow key script

```
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       
function KeyCheck() {

 var KeyID = event.keyCode;

  switch(KeyID)
  {

  case 37:

  right('img');

  break;

  case 38:

  up('img')

  break

  case 39:

  left('img');

  break;

  case 40:

  down('img');

  break;
  }
  }
```

and then the html

```
<img id="img" src="http://trevorrudolph.com/logo.png" style="position:absolute; left:1; bottom:1; right:1; top:1;">
```

you can download the html at [arrow.zip](http://trevorrudolph.com/arrow.zip)

the actual page is [here](http://trevorrudolph.com/arrow.html)

Comment: Have you tried debugging your javascript with Visual Studio or your browsers developer tools? It's best to step through and make sure the values of your variables are as you expect at each step. Otherwise I don't really understand your logic that well. As a side note you don't need to set Y to '5' then parseInt you can just set it to the number 5 and it is an int. You are missing semicolons on your break statements but that might just be when you typed it in here. Also I recommend running your javascript through jslint.com to make sure you haven't made any other mistakes.

Comment: You should really start using e.g. jQuery ;o - that will make your code much more readable and shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only be positioning it with `top` and `left`, because if you try to do it the way you're doing it, you are going to end up with very messed up properties, such as a `top` of say 5 but a `bottom` of say 100.

Also, you should use a unit, preferable pixels, for the `top` and `left` properties.

So, all you really need to do is change your functions to look like:

```
function left(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.left.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1; // get just the number and not the units
    document.getElementById(id).style.left = current - 1 + 'px'; // taking advantage of JavaScript's strange but sometimes useful type conversion. The subtraction converts it to an int and the addition converts it back to a string. 
}

function right(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.left.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.left = parseInt(current) + 1 + 'px'; // here we can't use that trick
}

function up(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.top.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.top = current - 1 + 'px';
}

function down(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.top.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.top = parseInt(current) + 1 + 'px';
}
```

Also, you should be using `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script language="JavaScript">`. The latter form is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

```
function move ( id, direction ) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    switch ( direction )
    {
    case "left":  element.style.left += 5; break;
    case "right": element.style.left -= 5; break;
    case "up":    element.style.top += 5;  break;
    case "down":  element.style.top -= 5;  break;
   }
}
```

Consider your code, look something like this. Less code, less getelementbyid, easy to change. You need only left and top style.

Edit: my mistake - string values must be inside "". Numeric values - don`t need.

Comment: how do i apply this to my code lets make it fresh with just <img id="img" src="http://trevorrudolph.com/logo.png" style="position:absolute; left:1; top:1;">

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `.right` property, subtract an amount from the `.left` property. This works for me. Additionally, try optimizing your code - your `if` clause does exactly the same thing in the `if` part and in the `else` part...